# Linking a new node to multiple directed graphs

Tags: python, networkx

I am looking for a way in networkx to link two graphs by a node from another graph.  After the linking, the resultant graph(the other graph) contains the two graphs' nodes in addition to its nodes. 
For example:

```
G=nx.DiGraph()
G.add_node(1)
G.add_node(2)
G.add_edge(1,2)

H=nx.DiGraph()
H.add_node(3)
H.add_node(4)
H.add_edge(3,4)

C=nx.DiGraph()
C.add_node(0)
C.add_node(5)
```

Now I would like to link node 0 in C graph to the first node of both G and H graphs (1,3) as well as linking the last node of both graphs (G and H) to node 5 in C graph.

I tried compose function but did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Graphs in `networkx` are separate entities from each other. You absolutely can't have a link from `Node1` in `Graph1` to `Node2` in `Graph2`. The only way you can represent a similar behaviour is to compose two graphs and create a link between their nodes. If two graphs are disjoint, you can use [union](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.operators.binary.union.html#networkx.algorithms.operators.binary.union) function. If they have equal nodes, you should use [compose](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.operators.binary.compose.html#networkx.algorithms.operators.binary.compose) function. But note two important things:

1. Both functions return a new graph. Old graphs are not changing.
2. If you use `compose` function, all elements that can be merged will be merged. For example:

```
import networkx as nx

G=nx.DiGraph()
G.add_nodes_from([1, 2, 3])
G.add_edges_from([(1, 2), (2, 3)])

H=nx.DiGraph()
H.add_nodes_from([5, 2, 3])
H.add_edges_from([(5, 2), (2, 3)])

Q = nx.compose(G, H)
Q.nodes()


NodeView((1, 2, 3, 5))
```

Nodes `1` and `2` were merged. So you should check all your nodes in both graphs if you don't want sudden merging.

Comment: you are right. I actually added two nodes to each graph( i.e node(0) as first node and node (5) as last node for each graph. And then used compose function to compose the two graph on the first and last node (node 0 and node 5). Thanks for pointing to compose function.